# How to get the print object "B" and "C" from a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

This is my JavaScript object:

```
{
    "A":{
        "B":[{
            "C":{
                "D":[{
                    "test" : "Hello"
                }]
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

From this how do I store objects B and C in a variable?

Comment: var variable1 = response.A.B,
var variable2 = variable1[0].c

Comment: This is not JSON. It's a JavaScript object. `B` and `C` are not objects. They are **properties**. Also, what do you mean by "print object"?

Comment: Accessing an object's properties is about as basic as using the plus sign to add two numbers. I suggest you go back and bone up on your JS basics. For property access, you could start off here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors.

Answer (score 0):

If `ob` is the object representation of the JSON, `ob.A.B` should give you `B`. And notice that `ob.A.B` is an array containing one object with key `C`. Hence `C` can be accessed as `ob.A.B[0].C`, the first element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Should be as simple as

```
 var a = {
"A":{
  "B":[{
    "C":{
      "D":[{
        "test" : "Hello"
      }]
    }
  }]
}
};

console.log( a.A.B ); //print the value of B
console.log( a.A.B[0].C ); //print the value of C
```

Answer (score -1):

suppose we are storing your json into a  variable `data`

```
data.A.B will give you Object B

and

data.A.B[0].C will give you Object C
```

Answer (score -1):

Since b is an array : console.log(obj.A.B[0].C)